How to configure slf4j and logback to allow one class to log to a separate file?
I have one Java class that is multithreaded and I want it to log to a separate file. I'm using Dropwizard which uses logback and is configured in my YAML file like this:
    logging:
  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO
  # Logger-specific levels.
  loggers:
    # Sets the level for 'com.example.app' to DEBUG.
    com.mycode: DEBUG

  appenders:
    - type: console
      threshold: DEBUG
    - type: file
      threshold: INFO
      logFormat: "%-6level [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
      currentLogFilename: /tmp/fingage.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /tmp/project-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 7
      timeZone: UTC
      maxFileSize: 10MB

Inside my special class I was trying something like:
//Obtain an instance of LoggerContext
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    //Create a new FileAppender
    FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> file = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    file.setName("FileLogger");
    file.setFile("specialclass.log");
    file.setContext(context);
    file.setAppend(true);

    //Filter out anything < WARN
    ThresholdFilter warningFilter = new ThresholdFilter();
    warningFilter.setLevel("WARN");
    warningFilter.setContext(context);
    warningFilter.start();
    file.addFilter(warningFilter);

    //Message Encoder
    PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    ple.setContext(context);
    ple.setPattern("%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} %msg%n");
    ple.start();
    file.setEncoder(ple);

    file.start();

    //Get ROOT logger, and add appender to it
    log = context.getLogger(MySpecialClass.class);
    log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    log.addAppender(file);

    log.info("Hello Special Class");

Unfortunately it doesn't appear to change anything, although I do a see a blank file specialclass.log and my log message appears only in the CONSOLE.

Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

The ThresholdFilter is set to WARN therefore only messages with this level and higher will be redirected to the file. Your info call at the end if your code is ignored because of this filter.

Thanks, I changed it to INFO but still I see no logging in the specialclass.log file defined earlier

Answer is to add the following in dropwizard YAML file:
    logging:
  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO
  # Logger-specific levels.
  loggers:
    
    com.mycode:
        level: DEBUG
        additive: false 
        appenders:
          - type: file
            currentLogFilename: /tmp/myclass.log
            

  appenders:
    - type: console
      threshold: DEBUG
    - type: file
      threshold: INFO
      logFormat: "%-6level [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
      currentLogFilename: /tmp/project.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /tmp/project-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 7
      timeZone: UTC
      maxFileSize: 10MB

